# Can I say "there are three pockets (for) this bag" ? Or should I say (to or in or on)?

Tags: prepositions

I've been teaching English for 2 months now, and there is this exercise that asks:

> There are two pockets ____ the bag.

The answer in the Answer Key notes is ON.

My students are adults so they tend to argue and I want to give them a correct answer and we have had a debate on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether the pockets on the inside or outside of the bag.

If inside, the correct preposition is 'in', otherwise the answer given is correct.

'to' should be used if there are pockets both inside and outside the bag, but, to me, it sounds pretentious. I would say:

> This bag has three pockets: one on the inside, two on the outside

or vice versa if that was the case.

Comment: **to** wouldn't be pretentious if referring to a feature.  *There are a couple of cool features to this bag which I really like.*